# Web Platform Installer freezes installing Azure 2.2 SDK

Tags: azure, windows-installer, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to install the Azure SDK 2.2 for VS2013 using the Web Platform Installer 4.6, but it never gets past step 2.  It doesn't matter how long I let it run and the only way to close the installer is to kill it with task manager.  I'm running Windows 8.

I've tried rebooting, uninstalling/reinstalling the Web Platform Installer but nothing seems to make a difference.

I had similar issues installing the SDK for VS2012, but found manual load instructions.  Unfortunately I can no longer find the manual install steps and was hoping someone might have an answer.

My log file
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https:\go.microsoft.com\?linkid=9824573
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : https:\go.microsoft.com\?linkid=9824573 responded with 302
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
    HTTP\1.1 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Length: 175
    Content-Type: text\html; charset=utf-8
    Expires: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:03:45 GMT
    Location: https:\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\webproductlist.xml
    Server: Microsoft-IIS\7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:45 GMT

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP\1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "b8763a951fbce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS\8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 791967743700000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR\2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:44 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-872341423.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 3, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP\1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "de62c4c9f0cf1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS\8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 27960443700000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR\2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:47 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\751837351.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 3, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\webapplicationlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\751837351.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP\1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "e62862cd116dce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS\8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 791312343100000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR\2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:49 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1953942818.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 3, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\mediaproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\1953942818.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\ToolsProductList.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\ToolsProductList.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP\1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "b57f3569ebfcce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS\8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 43877244200000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR\2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:49 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-95717523.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 3, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\ToolsProductList.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-95717523.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP\1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "a744a9fbddace1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS\8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 791855444000000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR\2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:49 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1709116680.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 3, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https:\\www.microsoft.com\web\webpi\4.6\enterpriseproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1709116680.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https:\\go.microsoft.com\?linkid=9824573' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-872341423.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http:\\go.microsoft.com\?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http:\\go.microsoft.com\?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP\1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text\html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:03:51 GMT
Location: http:\\www.microsoft.com\web\handlers\WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS\7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 22:04:51 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-Encoding header: 'gzip'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '21471'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '72697'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.2 (VWDOrVs2013AzurePack.2.2) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'VWDOrVs2013AzurePack.2.2'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'LightSwitchVS2013_AzurePublish_4_0_Only_BaseLocale
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureSDK_2_2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureStorageTools_2_2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2013.2.2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2013BaseLocale.2.2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WebToolsExtensionVS2013OnlyBaseLocale.2.1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WebToolsExtensionVWD2013OnlyBaseLocale.2.1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'Dev2013DevenvSetupHelper
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WebToolsExtensionVS2013.2.1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WebToolsExtensionVS2013Only.2.1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WebToolsExtensionVWD2013Only.2.1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'LightSwitchVS2013_AzurePublish.4.0
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http:\\download.microsoft.com\download\4\D\5\4D5A9603-7369-4631-897C-85D6967B3518\Preparation.exe' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp29F0.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '118872'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '118872'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\Dev2013DevenvSetupHelper\6D157151D4A1761F311E38EFA36B5024F04C173A\Preparation.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp29F0.tmp' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\Dev2013DevenvSetupHelper\6D157151D4A1761F311E38EFA36B5024F04C173A\Preparation.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http:\\download.microsoft.com\download\2\8\8\2886D7B8-3C4E-4372-8F86-474E06526299\WindowsAzureStorageTools.msi' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2B58.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Visual Studio 2013 Setup Helper' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Visual Studio 2013 Setup Helper done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '1159168'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '1159168'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageTools_2_2\130654C316ABB84CD6AFBCFC3B01B761F3CE1E5B\WindowsAzureStorageTools.msi' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2B58.tmp' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageTools_2_2\130654C316ABB84CD6AFBCFC3B01B761F3CE1E5B\WindowsAzureStorageTools.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http:\\download.microsoft.com\download\2\8\8\2886D7B8-3C4E-4372-8F86-474E06526299\WindowsAzureTools.vs120.exe' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2C15.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Storage Tools - v2.2'. Commandline is: 'C:\windows\sysnative\msiexec.exe \i "C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageTools_2_2\130654C316ABB84CD6AFBCFC3B01B761F3CE1E5B\WindowsAzureStorageTools.msi" \quiet \log C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureStorageTools_2_2.txt \msicl RUNDSINIT=1'. Process Id: 2692
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '5988792'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '5988792'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2013BaseLocale.2.2\A8BE987D110BB574EC77519C21F6437675806BA0\WindowsAzureTools.vs120.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2C15.tmp' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2013BaseLocale.2.2\A8BE987D110BB574EC77519C21F6437675806BA0\WindowsAzureTools.vs120.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http:\\download.microsoft.com\download\2\8\8\2886D7B8-3C4E-4372-8F86-474E06526299\WindowsAzureTools.LightSwitch.vs120.exe' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp32FB.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '918392'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '918392'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\LightSwitchVS2013_AzurePublish_4_0_Only_BaseLocale\929CFC940EB57E401CBF1B4BA556D4A3C99BEA32\WindowsAzureTools.LightSwitch.vs120.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp32FB.tmp' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\LightSwitchVS2013_AzurePublish_4_0_Only_BaseLocale\929CFC940EB57E401CBF1B4BA556D4A3C99BEA32\WindowsAzureTools.LightSwitch.vs120.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http:\\download.microsoft.com\download\2\8\8\2886D7B8-3C4E-4372-8F86-474E06526299\WebToolsExtensionsVWD2013.msi' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3473.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '30859264'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '30859264'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionVWD2013OnlyBaseLocale.2.1\84FFED54E59DC822B34218A4A4B1B643006CCA90\WebToolsExtensionsVWD2013.msi' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3473.tmp' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionVWD2013OnlyBaseLocale.2.1\84FFED54E59DC822B34218A4A4B1B643006CCA90\WebToolsExtensionsVWD2013.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http:\\download.microsoft.com\download\2\8\8\2886D7B8-3C4E-4372-8F86-474E06526299\WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4D1D.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '30871552'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '30871552'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionVS2013OnlyBaseLocale.2.1\7E4B58A5ED15C987AF0F6C4B105A5FD1638CBFD7\WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4D1D.tmp' to: C:\Users\Allen Jergensen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionVS2013OnlyBaseLocale.2.1\7E4B58A5ED15C987AF0F6C4B105A5FD1638CBFD7\WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi
```